# how to break loop in jquery in my code

Tags: jquery

How to break .each loop in JavaScript,

```
if(badCatsNames.length > 0)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < badCatsNames.length; i++) {
        var badCatName = badCatsNames[i];

        $("[id$=listAvailableCats] li").each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).text() == badCatName) {
                $(this).appendTo($("[id$=listPurchasingCats]"));
            }
            else {
                $("[id$=listPurchasingCats] li").each(function (index) {
                    if ($(this).text() == badCatName) {
                        $(this).appendTo($("[id$=listAvailableCats]"));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } 
}}
```

## What I want

If code finds bad cat name in availabel cats list then break and start again @ for loop

### If you can improve code too, please do :)

Comment: You can break a `.each` loop by doing `return false;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return true;` will skip the current iteration and head to the next, `return false;` will leave the `each` loop completely.

Comment: `return true;` is to `continue;` as `return false;` is to `break;` :-D

Answer (score 1):

you can use return false; to exit a loop at any time.

```
if(badCatsNames.length > 0)
{
for (var i = 0; i < badCatsNames.length; i++) {
    var badCatName = badCatsNames[i];

    $("[id$=listAvailableCats] li").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).text() == badCatName) {
            $(this).appendTo($("[id$=listPurchasingCats]"));
        }
        else {
            $("[id$=listPurchasingCats] li").each(function (index) {
                if ($(this).text() == badCatName) {
                    $(this).appendTo($("[id$=listAvailableCats]"));
         return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
} 
}};
```